# Cannot Select 'Keep personal files and apps' when updating to Windows 10 1903 after changing Program Files Directory?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

So, I have a 128GB SSD where Windows boots from and a 1TB HDD that I am using to store all my documents and my Program Files as I don't have an awful lot of storage space on my SSD.

I have changed my Program Files directory from my `C:\` drive (SSD) to my `D:\` drive (HDD) following this video tutorial [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LWEpXMBAtHg) updating both `Computer\HKEY\_LOCAL\_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\` and `Computer\HKEY\_LOCAL\_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\`

When I try use the [Media Install Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10) I get to the part where you can choose whether to
   - `Keep personal files and apps`
   - `Keep Personal files only`
   - `Keep Nothing`

However, only `Keep Nothing` is able to be selected, the other two are greyed out.

I move the Program Files directory back to `C:\` from `D:\` and now I can select all options.

I guess my question is. What should I do in this instance?

Should I select `Keep Nothing` when my Program Files are pointed to the `D:\` drive? What will actually happen in this scenario? Will that also format my `D:\` drive? Any potential instability issues?

Or point my Program Files to my `C:\` drive and select `Keep personal files and apps` then re point my Program files back to my `D:\` afterwards? Any potential issues with this?

Or any other solutions?

Any help will be greatly appreciated?

Comment: "I have changed my Program Files directory from my C:\ drive (SSD) to my C:\ drive (HDD)' - What?  How do you have the same drive letter assigned to two different volumes?  "Will, that also format my D:\ drive?" - No;  "Any potential instability issues?" - If you select "Keep Nothing" you will have to reinstall your applications and move your Program Files directory back to the new location.  "Keep Nothing" does not migrate anything from your current profile.  Any drive that is not your system disk isn't touched in this process.

Comment: @Ramhound, sorry, that was a typo, should have been from my C:\ drive to my D:\ drive. I've amended that typo in my question. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Undoing your redirection of Program Files back to C might help.

Comment: As for the underline problem of being unable to keep your personal files, that is actually due to the redirection, the workaround is to temporarily move it back to the default original location.  The only folder redirection that is supported can be done through a GUI, if you are manually modifying the register, there is a good chance that while it works it's actually untested (by Microsoft) and unsupported.

Comment: @Ramhound That's good to know. Thanks.